# How to create Athena table with selective bucket_names under a folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have an s3 location s3://s-dps/BK/MR

Under this MR I have folders A_20180501, A_20180502...... so on 
and D_20180501, D_20180502 .. so on

I tried with s3://s-dps/BK/MR/D_* and it gives me an error Not a valid s3 folder location.

Can I create an athena table with only D_* folders?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that. Ideally you should separate both kind of folders. If it's not possible for you to move all that content you have to rename the folders to follow a naming convention to consider it a partition. The naming convention is something like `partition_name=value`. 
An example for you could be something like `dateday=A_20180501`. If you have that, then you can create a table partitioned by dateday and query things like: `Select count(*) from myTable where dateday like 'D_%'`.

I hope this helps.